# How to set Prettier Comma Options?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using the prettier autosave feature very well.
But Only one problem arose.

when i save this code :

```
header, footer {
  ...
}
```

prettier converts it like this

```
header,
footer {
  ...
}
```

how i disable this option?

Answer (score 0):

That formatting occurs ([example on prettier.io](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBLAtgBwgJxgAmHwBM4AzVKOAYQi2gRgBp8c4BDMGVANzhchYArvGIs2ZFjAgAlcgGcWAd3YwwACwF1MIuMXwBffGRx18Ach5C45kExARM3aPOSh2OU0oAKHhK5R2ABsVAE9XewAjHE4AazgYAGVMTkoAc2QYHGt7OHRIvVJiABl2KDShdjS4ADFcdFVucuQQdhEIOxB1GHQggHV1VHh5FLA4RP8h3iHQlrB5CLQoeTg8bxi0huQyYJX7ACt5AA8AIRiweKT2dDhiyjht3f4QQ6PE9KC4AEUhCHhHoJ7EApHArHAtSLsApBTqYHCUGB9VDEGDqZAADgADPY4RAVn0YpgWnC4GC+J0AI6-eDrRwBVryAC0VD0ek6bCpqDY6yqWyQO0BzxW6FQmWyQo+32pD35T3sMChSJRaKQACZ5TFUEF0rR0HyQKSAKydIQrAAqUICAqBVjgAEkoKRYIkwPCnABBR2JGChT4AlYGAxAA)) when the line width exceeds the configured printWidth ([link on prettier documentation link description here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width)) (default is 80 characters). I assume your example is just a truncated version of a lengthy line, longer than 80 characters.

Increase `printWidth` to avoid the line wrapping:

```
// .prettierrc.js
module.exports = {
  printWidth: 120,
}
```

If using ESLint+Prettier (in a Vue CLI scaffolded project), configure ESLint's `prettier/prettier` options:

```
// .eslintrc.js
const prettierOptions = require("./prettierrc");

module.exports = {
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", prettierOptions],
  },
};
```

Be aware that Vetur only supports formatting the full document ([vue documentation](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/formatting.html)), so formatting a selected line does not work in SFC `<script>` blocks.